# I cannot cloneNode(true) in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This might seem like a very basic question, but I am currently doing a Javascript project.

My HTML only contains 2 divs (ids are "leftside" and "rightside", respectively). My CSS positioning for the image and divs are "absolute".

I am able to show 5 faces at random positions on the left div, but for some reason I cannot display any image on the right side using the cloneNode function. I really can't find anything, even syntax errors.

```
var faces = 5;

function createFaces(){

var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftside");
//var theRightSide = document.getElementByID("rightside");

for (i=0; i<faces; i++){
    var image = document.createElement("img");

    var randomX = Math.random() * 400;
    var randomY = Math.random() * 400;
    randomX = Math.floor(randomX);
    randomY = Math.floor(randomY);

    image.style.top = randomY + "px";
    image.style.left = randomX + "px";
    image.src = "images/smile.PNG";

    theLeftSide.appendChild(image);
    //document.getElementByID("rightside").appendChild(image);
}

var theRightSide = document.getElementByID("rightside");
var theClones = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
theRightSide.appendChild(theClones);

/*var theRightSide = document.getElementByID("rightside");
var theClones = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
theRightSide.appendChild(theClones);*/

}
```

Comment: Don't you want to clone `theRightSide` for the right side of your layout? So instead of `var theClones = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);` it shouldn't be `var theClones = theRightSide.cloneNode(true);`? Or does that matter? Hard to tell without HTML.... I assume if you deep clone `theLeftSide`, then it'll just  have the `position` of the left, ex. `left: 0`.

Comment: Could you provide us a jsFiddle or something?

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cfqnh6b4/1/

In my Chrome browser, the 5 images on the left appear. But here in jsFiddle, even the 5 leftside images do not appear.

Comment: @zer00ne I tried var theClones = theRightSide.cloneNode(true); but it still shows the same result. Anyway I have the original code for all 3 files in the link above.

Comment: @DarylG When cloning, be careful when cloning elements with id. I suggest that you use class on your elements instead. There's no style for `#theLeftSide`?